# how do I move the third h3 element to the left?

Tags: html, css

I tried using an id label to the third h3 element "Tri-Motor Cybertruck" to move it a bit to the left so it is kind of centered above the text below it. But that didn't work. I don't know what else I can do to solve this problem. I've googled around for a solution but didn't find anything.

```css
#demo {
  padding-top: 85px;
}

section ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#pricing {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  left: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

#pricing h3 {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 50px;
  left: 220px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

#tri-motor-cybertruck {
  position: relative;
  right: 100px;
}
```

```html
<section id="demo">
  <iframe id="video" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/m7atGkba-Z8" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</section>

<section id="pricing">
  <h3>Single-Motor Cybertruck</h3>
  <ul>
    <li>$39,900</li>
    <li>250+ miles of range</li>
    <li>0-60 moh in 6.5 seconds</li>
    <li>top speed of 110 mph</li>
  </ul>
  <h3>Dual-Motor Cybertruck</h3>
  <ul>
    <li>$49,900</li>
    <li>300+ miles of range</li>
    <li>0-60 moh in 4.5 seconds</li>
    <li>top speed of 120 mph</li>
  </ul>
  <h3 id="tri-motor-cybertruck">Tri-Motor Cybertruck</h3>
  <ul>
    <li>$69,900</li>
    <li>500+ miles of range</li>
    <li>0-60 moh in 2.9 seconds</li>
    <li>top speed of 130 mph</li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Comment: Please add image to help other visualize your issue, specially when dealing with css

Comment: please specify what image you would want for me to add. I feel that the code is sufficient as I would assume people would just copy and paste the code into their code editor and can see it from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say your code can be simplified. I added a `container` and nested each of your `h3`'s and `ul`'s in divs, and added a simple flex layout on your container with a gap on your other flex parent `#pricing`.

```css
#demo {
padding-top: 85px;
}

section ~ ul {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
}

#pricing {
display: flex;
gap: 50px;
}
```

```html
<section id="container">
<section id="demo">
 <iframe id="video" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/m7atGkba-Z8" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</section> 

<section id="pricing">
<div>
 <h3>Single-Motor Cybertruck</h3>
 <ul>
   <li>$39,900</li>
   <li>250+ miles of range</li>
   <li>0-60 moh in 6.5 seconds</li>
   <li>top speed of 110 mph</li>
 </ul>
</div>
<div>
 <h3>Dual-Motor Cybertruck</h3>
 <ul>
  <li>$49,900</li>
  <li>300+ miles of range</li>
  <li>0-60 moh in 4.5 seconds</li>
  <li>top speed of 120 mph</li>
 </ul>
</div>
<div>
 <h3 id="tri-motor-cybertruck">Tri-Motor Cybertruck</h3>
 <ul>
  <li>$69,900</li>
  <li>500+ miles of range</li>
  <li>0-60 moh in 2.9 seconds</li>
  <li>top speed of 130 mph</li>
 </ul>
</div>

 </section>
 </section>
```

Comment: I would do it like that too

Answer (score 1):

use this

```css
    #pricing #tri-motor-cybertruck {
            left: 200px;
    }
```

instead of

```css
    #tri-motor-cybertruck {
      position: relative;
      right: 100px;
    }
```

your problem was related with this theme [Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

Comment: You may want to elaborate more about how this relates to specificity (ID + element > ID, etc.) and why you changed it from using `right` to using `left`. You may also want to consider using the Copy snippet to answer button on the question's snippet so that the OP and others can see how your change improves the situation.